# ¿Cómo puedo seleccionar los elementos de mayor valor después de hacer un count en Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

Tengo esta situacion a traves de este `query`:

```
SELECT
  CST_CON_ID,
  X_TYPE_FOURTH_LVL,
  COUNT(X_TYPE_FOURTH_LVL) RAZON_MAS_FRECUENTE
FROM
  SIEBEL.S_SRV_REQ
GROUP BY
CST_CON_ID,
X_TYPE_FOURTH_LVL
ORDER BY
 CST_CON_ID;
```

obtengo la siguiente info, **ejemplo**:

```
ID USUARIO  TIPO    VECES QUE SE REPITE
1-1HQR-1380 Reposición de tarjeta   7
1-1HQR-1380 Cargos no reconocidos   4
1-1HQR-1380 Saldo   4
1-1HQR-1380 Bonificación de interés mayor   3
1-1HQR-1380 Información de la Cuenta    3
1-1HQR-1380 Saldo por Segmentos 3
1-1HQR-1380 Aviso de viaje al extranjero    2
1-1HQR-1380 Activación de Tarjeta   1
1-1HQR-1358 Alta    80
1-1HQR-1358 Cancelación 1
1-1HQR-1358 Envío Edo de cuenta por email   1
1-1HQR-1358 Estatus Solicitud  DILISA   1
1-1HQR-1358 Mal servicio de área crédito    1
1-1HQR-1358 Pagos Diferidos 1
1-1HQR-1323 Promoción Institucional 1
1-1HQR-1323 Robo de identidad 20
1-1HQR-1323 Cancelación 0
```

Lo que necesito es que solo me de el resultado siguiente:

```
ID USUARIO  TIPO    VECES QUE SE REPITE
1-1HQR-1380 Reposición de tarjeta   7
1-1HQR-1358   Alta               80
1-1HQR-1323 Robo de identidad   20
```

ya que dicho elemento es el que más repite en mi tabla

¿Alguien sabe cómo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bien después de algunas investigaciones esta es la respuesta

`SELECT ID_USER, ELEMENT_TYPE, T_REPEAT
 FROM (SELECT CST_CON_ID as ID_USER, X_TYPE_FOURTH_LVL as ELEMENT_TYPE,
             COUNT(X_TYPE_FOURTH_LVL) as T_REPEAT,
             dense_rank() OVER (PARTITION BY CST_CON_ID ORDER BY 
             COUNT(X_TYPE_FOURTH_LVL) DESC) AS Seq
        FROM SIEBEL.S_SRV_REQ
        GROUP BY CST_CON_ID, X_TYPE_FOURTH_LVL
       ) t
WHERE Seq = 1
ORDER BY ID_USER DESC;`

Answer (score 0):

Si solo quieres traer el que mas se repite con solo el limit puedes hacerlo, asi:

```
SELECT
      CST_CON_ID,
      X_TYPE_FOURTH_LVL,
      COUNT(X_TYPE_FOURTH_LVL) RAZON_MAS_FRECUENTE
FROM
      SIEBEL.S_SRV_REQ
GROUP BY
    CST_CON_ID,
    X_TYPE_FOURTH_LVL
ORDER BY
     CST_CON_ID
LIMIT 1;
```

esto proporciona solo la primera fila

Comment: Gracias srJJ, como comentaba hay mas elementos que 1-1HQR-1380 y lo que necesito es traer cada CST_CON_ID con su respectivo  X_TYPE_FOURTH_LVL mas repetido es por eso que quería implementar un MAX SALUDOS.